# How to call Block in product detailed page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, static-block

i had created custom block in content -> block -> xyz (block name) now i wan to call this block in product detailed page.

How can i call this block in product detailed page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Below code on **catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="unick_block_name">
    <arguments>
      <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">my_cmsblock_identifier</argument>
    </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

You need to replace "my_cmsblock_identifier" with your CMS block Identifier or ID (i recommend using Identifier).